# InfluxDB query measurements with multiple retention policy

Tags: influxdb

if I create multiple retention policy on a measurement, when I query the measurement, do I have to use

```
select * from RetentionPolicy.measurement
```

it looks to me the points with different retention policy has to be queried from a different measurement name with RetentionPolicy name as prefix?